# Understanding gets() function in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, gets

I am having a hard time trying to grasp some concepts in C and got confused with something that I got out of "C Programming Absolute Beginner's Guide" by Greg Perry.

By the end of the book the author mentions the workings of the function gets().He says that it returns a character pointer that points to the beginning of the string the user entered.If that is the case(and pardon my ignorance.I am really new at this) how is it that it returns the rest of the string?
My guessing was that it store a character array as full and that it would store it as the first element as such:

```
char * names[5] = {"name1","name2","name3"};
```

And from there we could do something like

```
printf("%s\n",*(names));
```

This would print "name1" because it is in fact returning the first position of the array.
But what about something like:

```
gets(names);
printf("%s\n",*(names));
```

The above example compiles fine but gives a segmentation error when I run it,if I .

I am sure that I am probably not interpreting the book correctly, but it seems to me as if the author says that gets assigns(in the above example) whatever the user enters in gets(names) as the first array element as a whole not in parts,the most I have been able to do is to print the first letter of whatever I type into names.

I keep getting fascinated by this little things as I feel they help me understand C programming(and programming as a whole) a lot better so I would definitely appreciate anyone that could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Just as a side note, `gets()` is deprecated and it shouldn't be used. You should probably look into `fgets()` as a safer alternative.

Comment: At this point in the life of the C language the only thing you really need to understand about `gets()` is its ranking among the most vile and evil library functions ever conceived. It is so bad it has been deprecated from the language. Debating the merit of how it works is a foregone argument; *terribly*.

Comment: @WhozCraig: It hasn't just been deprecated from the language, it's been removed entirely (as of the 2011 ISO C standard).

Comment: @KeithThompson I only wish I had a C11 toolchain at my disposal. Alas I'm currently forged in the VC world, where C-standards are an afterthought to C++ (which aren't much better). But your point is certainly valid, and I should have been clearer.

Answer (score 1):

A string in C is just a sequence of characters contiguous in memory. The function returns a pointer to the first character, and given that, through pointer arithmetic, you can look at the rest of the characters. There is no "returning the rest of the string": basically, it's returning something along the lines of "Hey, here's a pointer to the beginning of the string. You can start reading from that location".

For example, if `p` is the pointer to the first character, `p+1` is a pointer to the next character, and so forth. Strings are null terminated, so you know when to stop.

Side note: `gets()` is really dangerous because it is vulnerable to buffer overflow; it's obsolete. No one should be using that anymore. Read about `fgets()` instead.

`gets()` names is invalid, there is an immediate type mismatch. `names` decays into `char **`, and `gets()` is expecting a `char *`. Also, you have to provide a pointer to a valid memory location.

If you declared `names` like this:

```
char names[128];
```

Then `gets(names)` would be valid. Note that `gets()` has no way of knowing that `names` can hold at most 128 characters, and that's why you should be using `fgets()`, which receives the size of the buffer as an additional parameter so it knows its limits.

Comment: Thank you Filipe.A couple of more questions if I may. What is char **? and why is it that even when I point *names to a char array with enough space inside the most it lets me print out by using *(names) is one letter using just the %c conversion character? is there a way of printing a full string using *(names) and the conversion %s? I apologize for the question barrage and thank you for your time.

Comment: 1. `char **` is a pointer to pointer to `char`. Most of the time, when used in expressions, array names decay into a pointer to the first element. If you have an array of `char *` such as names, and the first element is a `char *`, then a pointer to the first element is `char **`.

Comment: 2. `*names` (or `*(names)` if you prefer) is equivalent to `names[0]`. In general, `*(names+i)` is equivalent to `names[i]`. Thus, `*(names)` will always print the first string in your array. You can print every string in `names` with a single call to `printf` like this: `printf("%s %s %s %s %s", names[0], names[1], names[2], ....)` up to `names[4]`.

Answer (score 0):

In C, a array is a list of contiguous memory blocks. So because these blocks are contiguous in memory, if you have the adress of the first, you have the adress of all of them.
For instance, with char c[3], the following equalities are true:

```
c[0] == *c
c[1] == *(c + sizeof(char));
c[2] == *(c + sizeof(char) * 2);
```

Comment: And of course, since `sizeof(char) == 1`, you don't need it.

Comment: Of course, but if you have int c[3]; instead, you need c[1] == *(c + sizeof(int));

Comment: @user3250340: No, you don't; pointer arithmetic is defined in units of the pointed-to type. `c[2]` is by definition equivalent to `*(c+2)`, regardless of the type of `c`.